# Python задачка по выводу таблицы умножения

Tags: python-3.x

Мучаюсь с задачей на Stepik. Нужно что бы программа выводила часть таблицы именно так как в задаче.

Логика кода у меня вроде правильная все работает на разных значениях.
Не могу с отступами сделать `"\t"` и `end=""`

Пример:

|  | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 |

Мой код:

```
a = int(1)
b = int(3)
c = int(2)
d = int(4)
for i in range(c,d + 1):
        for j in range(a,b + 1):
            print(i,end='*')
            print(j,end='=')
            print(i * j)
```

Буду рад за развернутый ответ.

Comment: А где учат так делать: ``a = int(1)``?

Comment: *«Нужно что бы программа выводила часть таблицы именно так как в задаче.»* - А где задача?

Answer (score 0):

В каком смысле "не можете"? Просто идёте по строчкам, а в строчках по колонкам - и делаете. Всё, что понадобится - это `end='\t'`. А циклы надо поменять местами, потому что внешний должен быть по строкам, а внутренний по столбцам. Ну и верхний заголовок лучше отдельно выводить (хотя есть варианты):

```
a = int(1)
b = int(3)
c = int(2)
d = int(4)
# верхний заголовок
print(end='\t')
for i in range(c,d + 1):
    print(i, end='\t')
print()
# таблица
for j in range(a,b + 1):
    # левый заголовок
    print(j, end='\t')
    # основная часть
    for i in range(c,d + 1):
        print(i * j, end='\t')
    print()
```

На выходе:

```
    2   3   4   
1   2   3   4   
2   4   6   8   
3   6   9   12
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
row = 2, 3, 4                              # кортеж вместо range()
col = 1, 2, 3

print("   ", end="")                       # пропуск 3 позиций в заголовке
for n in row:
    print(f"{n:3}", end="")
print()

for m in col:
    print(f"{m:3}", end="")                # сначала заголовок строки произведений
    for n in row:
        print(f"{m*n:3}", end="")          # отдельные произведения
    print()
```

---

*Результат:*

> ```
>      2  3  4
>   1  2  3  4
>   2  4  6  8
>   3  6  9 12
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

Шаблон один и тот же:

- Для вывода всякого числа используем [f-string](https://python-scripts.com/f-strings) *с резервированием 3 позиций* (`:3`):

  - одной как сепаратора (т.к. числа сравниваются вправо),
  - двух для самого числа.
- Всякое число выводим функцией `print()` с параметром `end=""`, чтобы остаться в той-же строке.
- После заполнения каждой строки применим `print()` для перехода к новой.

---

*Замечание:*

Так как [f-string](https://python-scripts.com/f-strings) доступен только в версиях Питона 3.6+, для предыдущих версии надо вместо него применить метод `.format()`.

Например вместо

```
            f"{m*n:3}"
```

используйте

```
            "{:3}".format(m*n)
```